# how to define permission for user roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

I am building user authorization from scratch and have been working on the user roles. I am stuck on the permissions part as I am not sure how to define it. When I add "before_filter :authorize" to a controller it shows a " "uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Permission"" error on all pages.

I know the error is steaming from my application_controller.rb file:

```
  def current_permission
    @current_permission || Permission.new(current_user)
  end

  def authorize
    if !current_permission.allow?(params[:controller], params[:action])
      redirect_to root_url, alert: "Not authorized."
    end
```

Permission.rb:

```
Class Permission < Struct.new(:user)
  def allow?(controller, action)
    if user.nil?
    controller == "galleries" && action.in?(%w[index show])
  elsif user.admin?
    true
  else
    controller == "galleries" && action != "destroy"
  end
  end
```

What I don't know is how to define permissions in my app properly so that I do not receive that error. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is Permission an ActiveRecord model ? Or a simple object ? Where have you defined it ?

Comment: I just added my permission.rb file.

Comment: Yeah, see my answer below; you **definitely** should take a look at **[pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Permission` class has 2 issues:

1. `Class` should be `class` with a lowercase `c`.
2. You are missing an `end` to close the class.

---

I also have to point out that there's really no reason to reinvent the wheel. Many choose to use [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) or [declarative_authorization](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization) to do what yo'ure trying to accomplish.

Personally, I like the much more lightweight [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) gem, which seems to fit into what you're trying to accomplish quite nicely.

Comment: That did not work. I did a edit and included my permission.rb file in the original post. I have basic authorization needs, and was told CanCan is more for explicit preferences. I have two roles only, minus guest/banned. Besides that it's just registered and admin. I'm new to Rails and I would prefer to see how it all works instead of just using plugging in some gems. I was able to get CanCan to work yesterday, but I prefer doing coding from scratch so I can learn more.

Comment: Where is `permission.rb` located? Can you run `Permission.new(User.first)` without trouble from the console?

Comment: Did you restart your server after adding it? Also, though I understand where you're coming from regarding wanting to learn, reading through existing source code is an **excellent** way to gain a better understanding of Ruby and Rails.

Comment: The only other advice I can offer is to try renaming your class.

Comment: Perhaps maybe I need to use a library for permissions. As I haven't defined permissions yet

Comment: Also, maybe it's just a typo...but you have `Class Permission < Struct.new(:user)`. The `c` in `class` should be lowercase.

Comment: lol well that was a issue, thanks. Now I just going to fix this unexpected end-of-input on permission.rb and then perhaps this should all work. Good eye!

Comment: You need to add a final `end` to the file. You're not closing the `Permission` class. I updated my answer to reflect these changes; I'd appreciate an upvote/accept if it solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help as I was stuck on something so simple for quite some time